# Turn off Autocorrect Globally in an App

Tags: ios, ipad

I would like to disable text-entry autocorrect in an iPad application, regardless of what the global settings for autocorrect are on the device. Is there a good way to do this through the API, or will I simply need to go through the whole app, find all text entry fields, and turn the option off for each field individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im sorry but you have to go trough all the text fields and disable it

Comment: creating a category for that should be a better solution IMHO

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default text field autocorrection type with a bit of [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/). In your app delegate or somewhere else sensible:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

// Prevent this code from being called multiple times
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    struct objc_method_description autocorrectionTypeMethodDescription = protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(UITextInputTraits), @selector(autocorrectionType), NO, YES);
    // (Re)implement `-[UITextField autocorrectionType]` to return `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNO`.
    IMP noAutocorrectionTypeIMP = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(UITextField *_self){ return UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; });
    class_replaceMethod([UITextField class], @selector(autocorrectionType), noAutocorrectionTypeIMP, autocorrectionTypeMethodDescription.types);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably subclass UITextField and set your desired properties to it. Instead of the UITextField you can use this subclassed version.

This may be worthy if you haven't started implementing your application yet!

Comment: I have, alas, started the app, and need to defend against other programmers on the project adding their own text fields. It's a good idea, though, and I would use it in other circumstances.

Comment: How about adding a category of UITextField then? Disable the autocorrect inside the category.

Answer (score 0):

as `@cocoakomali` suggested, you can create a *category* of `UITextField` to disable autocorrect for all `UITextField` in the app by default

```
@implementation UITextField (DisableAutoCorrect)

- (instancetype)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    [self setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: You shouldn't override a designated initializer in a category class. Even worse, a category class is not meant for overrides, this will create a conflict soon or later.

Comment: @DZenBot, I understand a category class is generally not meant for overrides, but the OP is asking for a way to turn off autocorrect globally, and unfortunately Apple doesn't seem to provide any other convenient way to do it, so this is probably one of the most convenient/reasonable solutions to achieve this. IMHO, I don't think this category is vulnerable to conflicts since it just append a call to `setAutocorrectionType:` after the default `init`, so I expect it to be as safe as doing `[[[UITextField alloc] init] setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo]`

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable globally but what you can do is extend UIViewController to loop on all textfields and disable autocorrect

**Extension :**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func removeAutocorrect() {
        self.view.allSubviews.forEach { v in
            if let textField = v as? UITextField {
                textField.autocorrectionType = .no
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage :**

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Do other stuff here

        //Must be called after adding all your TextField subviews
        self.removeAutocorrect()
    }
}
```