# Is there a way to disable predictive text off for the entire ios app like UIAppearance protocol?

Tags: ios, user-interface, keyboard

The autocorrection / predictive text feature is generally not desired in the app. I'd like to make a user preference if they would like to disable it for the app but not require them to turn it off across the phone. Is there a way to do this? The documentation doesn't speak to this at all or maybe it does and I just got lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable UITextField Predictive Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767522/disable-uitextfield-predictive-text)

Comment: That provides you with the solution, this provides you with the actual answer which is NO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670321/turn-off-autocorrect-globally-in-an-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can do it by assigning the property **autocorrectionType** to false in every textfield that you have.
2. You can subclass UITextField class and use it in every view controller that you want.
3. You can use [Method Swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) in order to auto set this property for UITextField class

Comment: Oh interesting with method swizzling - do you know if that would work if its a view that I have a <UIKeyInput> protocol on too?

Comment: @AnkitKapasi, I don't think so, a view with just UIKeyInput you can't access to autocorrectionType property. Instead would be better to create a category on UITextField and apply method swizzling. If this answers your question could you mark it as correct? :) thank you

Comment: darn. I have a UIViewController that doesnt have a textfield... definitely happy to mark this answer good because I like the Method Swizzle option. Thanks man.